# Unwanted quotes in text of dialog box called by osascript

Tags: bash, applescript

I manage Macs at work and I am building a tool to run a diagnostic and display the fail results in a dialog box along with offering the chance to "save" a .txt file continuing a longer more detailed report.  The best way I found to display the dialog box is with osascript and I have it working nicely, however, there are quotes around the text displayed.  I think this is related to the fact that I am calling a variable for the text that is set earlier in the bash script dependent on how many failures I have added to a particular array.  In the case of that array NOT being g empty, that text also calls ANOTHER variable to get a more aesthetically pleasing version of the array items.  I can't really change what the text contains and how it is displayed, and anywhere I try removing quotes seems to just break everything.

Here is the code

```
## Dialog Box

# let's get the array to only list one item per line
niceList=$(printf '%s\n' "${failArray[@]}")

if [ ${#failArray[@]} -eq 0 ] ; then
    dialogText="All checks passed.  

You may close this window or save the full report."
else
    dialogText="The following items have failed:   

$niceList

You may close this window or save the full report."

fi

osascript << EOF

set report to POSIX file "/Users/Shared/Mac Health Check.txt"

display dialog "\$dialogText\"" with title "Mac Health Check" buttons {"Close", "Save Report"} default button "Close"

if result = {button returned:"Save Report"} then
    set savePath to choose folder
    tell application "Finder"
        move file report to folder savePath
    end tell
else if result = {returned:"Close"} then
    tell application "Finder"
        delete file report
    end tell
end if
EOF
```

Again, this is currently working as intended with the only exception of all text in the dialog box being quoted.  I have been told to remove those quotes by someone who doesn't care about my suffering.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Get rid of `\"`

Comment: Why are you escaping the `$` with `\$`? That will prevent the variable from being substituted into the script.

Comment: I thought I had to do that in order for AppleScript to read the variable that is set previously in bash?

Comment: AppleScript isn't reading the variable, it's being expanded as part of the here-doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not expanding the `$dialogText` variable because you escaped the `$`. And you're adding an extra quote with `\"`. Change that line to:

```
display dialog "$dialogText" with title "Mac Health Check" buttons {"Close", "Save Report"} default button "Close"
```

Note that you need to ensure that you don't put any double quotes in `dialogText`, as they'll match the double quotes used to delimit the string in the `display dialog` command.

Comment: I overthought it!  Thanks Barmar!